# Reverse-i-search jumps back in time!

Tags: command-line, search, bash-history

Sometimes I want to search for a previously executed command in my console.

So I press `Ctrl + R` and I enter in `(reverse-i-search)` mode. I start typing my command and I press `Ctrl + R` again and again to cycle through all previous commands that match the input text.

However after doing that, if I press the up or down keys I see the commands I executed long time ago, just before of after the command I just searched.

Looks like the command history "jumped" to the searched command.

My question: Is there a way of restoring my command history to the latest one, so when I press up I should see the latest commands I executed? I don't want my up and down keys to show me what I executed back then, but rather the latest commands I introduced.

I can keep my down key pressed for a while until I reach the last command, but I'm sure it must be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to cancel input, and you'll get back to the present.